# Why does assigning result of a map function to one variable differs from assigning it to several variables?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, map-function, variable-expansion

Here I have input 2 strings `"12"` and `"123 54 856 78 "` to the same function but one gets converted to `int` while other doesn't:

```
str="12"
a=map(int,str.split())
print(type(a)) #o/p :<class 'map'>
print (a) #o/p :<map object at 0x7f432e95a630>


str1="123 54 856 78 "
a1,b1,c1,d1=map(int,str1.split())
print(type(a1)) #o/p :<class 'int'>
print (a1) #o/p :123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first call to map (`a=map(int,str.split())`) you are setting a to the map object. In the second call to map (`a1,b1,c1,d1=map(int,str1.split())`) you are setting the values of your map function to the different values generated by the map function. if you instead had

```
a1 = map(int(str1.split())
print(type(a1)) # <class 'map'>
```

Answer (score 1):

The map function:

> Python map() function is used to apply a function on all the elements
>   of specified iterable and **return map object**. Python map object is an
>   iterator, so we can iterate over its elements. We can also convert map
>   object to sequence objects such as list, tuple etc. using their
>   factory functions.
>
> We can pass multiple iterable arguments to map() function, in that
>   case, the specified function must have that many arguments. The
>   function will be applied to these iterable elements in parallel. With
>   multiple iterable arguments, **the map iterator stops when the
>   shortest iterable is exhausted**.

Source: https://www.journaldev.com/22960/python-map-function

What this means is that by default the map function returns a map. But when specifying more as one variable it tries to map the items in the map to the specified variables. So using only one variable and one value in the string, it does not work.

That is just how the map function works.